# How can I change stack reserve size when I use node to call C++?

Tags: c++, node.js

I want to use a C++ function in my nodejs project.
When I just run the C++ function, I need set the stack reserve size bigger to make sure it works.
But how can I set it when I use nodejs to call the C++ function?

I found the .vcxproj file in nodejs project which should be the configure as the properties in C++ project. I also found the  in .vcxproj file, and try to directly add a new line like XXX, but it doesn`t work.
I also try to increase the max stack size to node project, but it seems like the stack size in node project and the c++ project which called by node are not the same thing.

Comment: Why do you need to change the stack size ?

Comment: Reference material: [Child process](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/child_process.html), [C++ Addons](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/addons.html)

Answer (score 0):

I want to change the stack size, because the C++ code is programmed by other guy, who use a big two dimension array. Changing all the array into heap is not a easy work, because I am not very familiar with the long code. But I am sure that if I increase the stack size, the code works.